# how to remove feed from embeded tiktok video in landing page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using this embedded code for the TikTok video on my landing page and I want to remove the feed below the video and just want to display the video with no text.
i tried to remove this using css and javascript by didn't work.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
  <div class="box">
  <blockquote class="tiktok-embed" cite="https://www.tiktok.com/@bighatmagic/video/6917125669415701765" data-video-id="6917125669415701765" style="max-width: 605px;min-width: 325px;" > <section> <a target="_blank" title="@bighatmagic" href="https://www.tiktok.com/@bighatmagic?refer=embed">@bighatmagic</a> How to Stretch a Hat ~ all you need is a hat stretcher + steamer  <a title="hat" target="_blank" href="https://www.tiktok.com/tag/hat?refer=embed">#hat</a> <a title="hatmaker" target="_blank" href="https://www.tiktok.com/tag/hatmaker?refer=embed">#hatmaker</a> <a title="customhat" target="_blank" href="https://www.tiktok.com/tag/customhat?refer=embed">#customhat</a> <a title="malibu" target="_blank" href="https://www.tiktok.com/tag/malibu?refer=embed">#malibu</a> <a title="teressafoglia" target="_blank" href="https://www.tiktok.com/tag/teressafoglia?refer=embed">#teressafoglia</a> <a title="femalemaker" target="_blank" href="https://www.tiktok.com/tag/femalemaker?refer=embed">#femalemaker</a> <a title="fyp" target="_blank" href="https://www.tiktok.com/tag/fyp?refer=embed">#fyp</a> <a title="foryourpage" target="_blank" href="https://www.tiktok.com/tag/foryourpage?refer=embed">#foryourpage</a> <a target="_blank" title="♬ CRAFT - OFEKNIV" href="https://www.tiktok.com/music/CRAFT-6732297013599143937?refer=embed">♬ CRAFT - OFEKNIV</a> </section> </blockquote> <script async src="https://www.tiktok.com/embed.js"></script>
    
    
    
  </div>
</div>
```

`